# Order data on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I currently have a ggplot however it is shown in alphabetical order, I want the graph to show the most 'important score' first and order in descending order. See image of plot attached and code.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data= VIMP, aes(x=(VIMP$Y),y=VIMP$X)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity",width = 0, color = 
"black") + 
 coord_flip() + geom_point(color='skyblue') + 
xlab("Variables")+ylab(" Importance Score")+
 ggtitle("Variable Importance") + 
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
 theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 
'black'))
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `forcats::fct_reorder`? Or you can convert your character column to factor and specify its levels.

Comment: Provide Sample data.

Comment: sample data attached @Rushabh

Comment: We can't use data from images.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you might use the `library(forcats)` package. Forcats is a package that was made to deal with factors in R.
This code might work for you.

```
VIMP <- VIMP %>%
 mutate(Y = forcats::fct_reorder(Y, X)) ##reorder the Y variable based on X, it's also possible to change to a descending order using desc(X).

ggplot(data= VIMP, aes(x=(VIMP$Y),y=VIMP$X)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity",width = 0, color = 
"black") + 
 coord_flip() + geom_point(color='skyblue') + 
xlab("Variables")+ylab(" Importance Score")+
 ggtitle("Variable Importance") + 
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
 theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))
```